# How to log Windows eventlog to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012

I have to change Windows 2012 Server event log (`.evtx` file) location (Windows to SQL Server database file). Can I log all event data in SQL Server and print (date and time wise) them in Crystal Report as and when required. In SQL Server?

Is there any solution and suggestion to do this?

Comment: You can do it with a Powershell script. See [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/storing-windows-event-viewer-output-in-a-sql-server-table-with-powershell/) fro the details

Comment: Thanks!!, Let me try then ill tell you or if any further assistance require ill do the comments.